# IE 10, 11 & Edge shaky on hover animation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, transform, scale

I have a simple example (https://jsfiddle.net/5x9yLyxq) with two "tiles" that have a hover function (only css, no javascript).

The initial status of them is this

```
.tiles div{
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

and I then have a :hover css which looks like this:

```
.tiles div:hover{
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
   box-shadow: 0 0 11px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

**Problem: In IE (any, even Edge) the zoom animation "shakes" (looks really bad).**

Does anyone know anyway to make the animation smooth (like in Chrome), can be a js library or css I do not care, just needs to be smooth?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've found this to be caused by the transform-origin property, which defaults to 50%.

If you change this to a value just over that, the shakiness (magically) stops. Try adding the following to your stylesheet:

```
transform-origin: 50.01%;
```

`transform-origin` is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform-origin) for IE8 and up, Edge, and all other major browsers.

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/badfreja/3n1qp38z/2/) based on the JSfiddle originally posted by @DavidDunham.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

> -ms-transform: scale(1.1);

for IE 9 or greater version.